# Select com opção do banco de dados usando laravel 5.8

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

Preciso que meu select busque as opções dentro do banco de dados em uma tabela.
Encontrei uma forma, não acontece nada ao carregar a pagina(Nem erro) e não apareçe nenhuma opção no select, alem que tentei debugar com dd('teste') na função do controller e nada...

Select HTML:

```
<select type="text" class="idmatricula form-control" name="idmatricula" id="idmatricula" required></select>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.idmatricula').select({
        placeholder: 'Selecione a Matricula',
        ajax: {
            url: 'Ferias/PreencheSelect',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function (data) {
                console.log('teste');
                return {
                    results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.idmatricula +' | '+ item.nome,
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        success:function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function PreencheSelect()
    {
        dd('select');
        $select = Matricula::pluck('id', 'nome');
        return with('select', $select);
    }
```

Rota:

```
route::post('Ferias/PreencheSelect', ['as' => 'ferias.preencheselect','uses' => 'General\FeriasController@PreencheSelect']);
```

Como faço para isso funcionar?Maioria dos resultados encontrados na net nao funciona.

obs: coloquei console.log na expectativa de ter algum retorno...

Answer (score -2):

Igor, se entendi bem você está retornando uma variável com os dados no seu controller, na requisição ajax você espera simplesmente um JSON, substitua sua função PreencheSelect() no controller pela seguinte:

```
public function PreencheSelect()
{
    $select = Matricula::pluck('id', 'nome');
    return $select;
    // ou ainda, caso esteja usando a facade Response no seu controller, pelo seguinte:
    // return Response::json($select);
}
```

Depois nos conte o resultado para que possamos investigar melhor.

Obs: para utilizar o a funçao dd você deve chamá-la após o argumento passado ter sido declarado, como por exemplo:

```
public function PreencheSelect()
{
    $select = Matricula::pluck('id', 'nome');
    dd($select); // passe a variável, não uma string;
}
```

Para testar o retorno, você pode alterar sua rota de post para get e acessar a URL diretamente.